# Save a matplotlib plot to a file using the command line without using plt.save()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a script that creates a plot and then shows it:

(The following script is an example from the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/simple_plot.html))

```
# coding: utf-8
# file: test_plot.py

import yaml

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def plot():
    t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
    plt.plot(t, s)

    plt.xlabel('time (s)')
    plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
    plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plot()
```

If this script is executed from the command line ( `python test_plot.py` ) it correctly shows the plot.

The question is: It is possible to save the plot to a file *without* modifying the code?

Comment: `plt.savefig("test.png")` doesn't save the figure?

Comment: Since this code already saves the plot as an image on disk, you do indeed not need to modify the code at all. Somehow this makes it a bit questionable what this question asks about though.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake at the moment of copying/pasting the code. The actual script doesn't have a `plt.save`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without modifying the code you can of course not change its outcome. So I will interprete this as "without modifying the `plot` function". I.e. you can modify anything that's below `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

In that case you may turn interactive mode on while calling the function and turn it off afterwards.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    plt.ion()
    plot()
    plt.ioff()
    plt.savefig("trala.png")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: So, is not it possible to redirect the output of that script to a file, so the image is stored there? Something like `python test_plot.py > my_image.png`?

Comment: This script does not have any output which you can redirect.

Comment: I was assuming that the plot is an _output_ ... (even when the plot is not going to the `stdout`, but I was wondering if maybe there is a way of redirecting the video or graph output...)

Comment: The plot is a graphical user interface, i.e. a program with an event loop. I mean you can't do `firefox > my_image.png` either, right?